# How to use authorizationChecker inside a trait

Tags: symfony, traits

I have a trait that checks if a user is logged in or not and number of attempts to a specific location.

This trait I am trying to use inside a FormType in order to display a captcha after a number of attempts.

Inside `getIpOrUserId()` I am trying to check if user is logged in  `$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')` but it returns an error
`Attempted to call an undefined method named "get" of class`.

I don't think that it is possible to create a Trait as a Service so I can inject the security object.

Is there a way to achieve this?

> Trait

```
<?php

Trait CheckAttempts {

public function getTryAttempts()
{
    if ($this->getIpOrUserId() == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $attempts = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('SiteBundle:LoginAttempts')
            ->findOneByIpOrUserId($this->getIpOrUserId());
    }

    return $attempts->getAttempts();
}

protected function getIpOrUserId()
{
     //get logged in user
    //if ($this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
      if ($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
        $ipOrUserId = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser()->getId();            
    } else {
        $ipOrUserId = $this->container->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest()->getClientIp();
    }
    return $ipOrUserId;
}
```

> FormType

```
class RegisterType extends AbstractType
{

use FormSendLimitTrait;

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {

    $form = $event->getForm();
    var_dump($this->getTryAttempts());

    $form->add('captcha', 'captcha', 
          'label' => 'site.captcha'
    ]);

    /*if ($attempts->getAttempts() > 6) {
        $form->add('captcha', 'captcha', [
            'label' => 'site.captcha'
        ]);
    }*/
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get` method works only if you extend `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller` class, usually it is used inside your controller classes. And it returns only `$this->container->get($id)`, nothing else, this means it returns `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container` class. You should inject `security.authorization_checker` service into your class (or other services which you want), or even whole `service_container` service (**but it's not recommended**).

Example:

```
class MyClass
{
    private $securityChecker;

    public function __construct(Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker $securityChecker)
    {
        $this->securityChecker = $securityChecker;
    }

    ...
}
```

services.yml

```
services:
    my_class_service:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\MyClass
        arguments: 
           - @security.authorization_checker
```

**But** in your case [you should not use traits like you're doing](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/74077/trait-accessing-variables-of-classes-using-it).